# OpenCV Native Android cvtColor crash

Tags: c++, opencv, android

I need to convert an image to grayscale and then back to RGBA to be able to draw in it.

Currently, I am doing it with two different cvtColor calls, which works fine, although the performance is not good in Android (RGBA -> GRAY -> RGBA).

Getting a gray image from the camera directly is faster and only having to do one cvtColor call makes a huge difference (GRAY -> RGBA).

The problem is that the second method makes the app close after a few seconds. The logcat in Android Studio does not show a crash for the app, but it shows some errors with the No Filters option selected. Here is the log https://pastebin.com/jA7jFSvu. It seems to point to a problem with OpenCV's camera.

Below are the two different pieces of code.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    // Method 1 - works
    cameraImage = inputFrame.rgba();
    native.exampleProcessImage1(cameraImage.getNativeObjAddr(), cameraImage.getNativeObjAddr());

    return cameraImage;

    // Method 2 - app closes after a few seconds
    cameraImage = inputFrame.gray();
    Mat result = new Mat();
    native.exampleProcessImage2(cameraImage.getNativeObjAddr(), result.getNativeObjAddr());

    return result;
}
```

And this is my code in C++:

```
void Java_com_example_native_exampleProcessImage1(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jlong sourceImage, jlong destImage) {
    // works!
    Mat &src = * ((Mat *) sourceImage);
    Mat &dest = * ((Mat *) destImage);
    Mat pivot;

    // src is RGBA
    cvtColor(src, pivot, COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    cvtColor(pivot, dest, COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
    // dest is RGBA

    // process
}

void Java_com_example_native_exampleProcessImage2(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jlong sourceImage, jlong destImage) {
    // does not work
    Mat &src = * ((Mat *) sourceImage);
    Mat &dest = * ((Mat *) destImage);

    // src is GRAY
    cvtColor(src, dest, COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
    // dest is RGBA

    // process
}
```

This works as expected on Linux and OpenCV.

Do you know what I am doing wrong? Is there another way to achieve the same? Performance is key, in particular for Android devices.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For second case you have memory leak and this leads to leak
`~ 3 sec * fps * frame_resolution * 4 bytes`

I think crash is happening after the memory is full.

You need to call `result.release();` somewhere after each `exampleProcessImage2` call

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion pointed me in the right direction. I did not know that I had to release the memory, and the error report wasn't very clear.